# Django view doesn't accept POST from html

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am making a login view, but I get an error indicating that POST method is not allowed.

This is the view class:

```
class LogIn(View);
    def get(self, request):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)

                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('control_center'))
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Account not active!')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid user/name!')
        else:
            return render(request, 'UserManagerApp/login.html', {})
```

And this is the html form:

```
<form action="{% url 'UserManagerApp:login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="card-body">
      <label for="email">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="example@attractora.com">
      <label for="password" style="padding-top: 10px">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">Accept</button>
      <button type="cancel" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

And this is the error I get:

```
[01/Feb/2018 21:00:45] "GET /user_manager/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1686
Method Not Allowed (POST): /user_manager/login/
[01/Feb/2018 21:11:25] "POST /user_manager/login/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

I am following some online directions but, evidently, I went astride at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a separate function called `post()` in your LogIn class. You have only defined a `get()` method which only handles `GET` requests.

See the [Django documentation on class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views) for more information.

Comment: Doh! Got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get(self, request):
```

A method with this name will never be called with `request.method == 'POST'`; `def post(...)` for that.